# what are the conclusions obtained from this box plot?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, statistics

I have plotted the standard deviation of different regions.Can anyone help me to get the conclusions from this boxplot. I just want to conclude the properties of regions. In this figure, eigth object is odd one. What is the significance of whiskers?

How to change the xlabel as region1 ,region2 etc

[image]

Comment: Can you help us to get the conclusions on your question ?

Comment: what we can infer about the regions?

Answer (score 2):

Coclusions: wide part of your data does not follow a normal distribution. You need something like [Violin Plots](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23661-violin-plots-for-plotting-multiple-distributions--distributionplot-m-) to see what is rally happening in your data.

Specially for 3-7, as it seems that the number of the outliers is too big.

But remember: Conclusions are obtained from data, not from the plotting option you chose for your data!

about changing the xlabel.... have you tried the function [`xlabel`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlabel.html)....?

Comment: actually the eight data is odd one

Comment: How to change the xlabel as region1 ,region2 etc

Comment: @abcd check my  update. Indeed the 8th is also different. I really suggest you try violin plots. Boxplot oversimplify the data.